# Organize my array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

im trying to optimize my code as much as possible and i've reached a dead end.

my code looks like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :age
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end

people = [Person.new(10), Person.new(20), Person.new(30)]

newperson1 = [Person.new(10)]
newperson2 = [Person.new(20)]
newperson3 = [Person.new(30)]
```

Is there a way where i can get ruby to automatically pull data out from the people array and name them as following newperson1 and so on..

Best regards

Comment: Why would you want to? Just use them from the array. Or create a hash with keys of "newperson" + an index.

Comment: Im quite new to ruby and as i said trying to optimize my code. can u make a example of using an hash for this example

Comment: If you have a collection of things, the optimal way to use it is as a collection, rather than pulling out separate variables. That's very unlikely to be an optimization. If what you want is to be able to have an identifier for each item, then a hash may be a good approach. For how to do it, look at sawa's example, but instead of setting a local variable using binding, first create a hash `myhash = {}` and then just do `myhash["newperson#{1}"] = person`.

Comment: in your code above you've actually created 6 Person objects and 4 arrays, just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely a code smell. You should refer to them as `[people[0]]`, `[people[1]]`, ... .

But if you insist on doing so, and if you can wait until December 25 (Ruby 2.1), then you can do:

```
people.each.with_index(1) do |person, i|
  binding.local_variable_set("newperson#{i}", [person])
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're trying to do...

```
newperson1 = people[0]
puts newperson1.age
```

The output of this `10` as expected.